Who in 1st century CE China discovered the connection between tides and lunar phases?
Cohen (2015) speaks of the Chinese

discovery in the first century CE of the connection between the tides and the phases of the Moon.

Who made this discovery and what exactly did they discover? (Cohen gives no sources.)

Briefly googling I can't seem to find much, except that Shen Gua/Shen Kuo (1031–1095)

argues against the theory that tides are caused by the rising and setting of the sun and demonstrates that they correlate rather with the cycles of the moon.

But this is much later than the "first century CE".

See this post in general and Zhang Heng (AD 78–139) and Shen Kuo. It seems that they had "modern" views about the Moon, but not specifically wrt tides.

Cartwright describes his On The Origins Of Knowledge Of The Sea Tides From Antiquity To The Thirteenth Century  as "an exhaustive survey of the first written records concerning sea-tides and hypotheses
for their cause, covering a period from 500 B.C.E. to 1250 C.E." Judging by his account, Cohen is referring to a skeptical writer Wang Chhung who repudiated in the 1st century AD China earlier mythological 'explanations' of the tides by the wrath of a wrongfully slain minister Wu Tzu-Hsu:

"The largest bores on the Ch'hien Thang were known to be associated with Full
(and New?) Moons since pre-Christian times, but before 1923 western scholars
knew only of superstitious legends to account for them. Most well known was
the legend that the bore is due to the wrath of a certain general or senior minister
who had been murdered in the fourth century B.C.E. and his body cast into the
river. This story was related, for example by Darwin in his popular book on
tides. A China scholar named Arthur C. Moule (1873-1957) knew of much
more esoteric accounts in Chinese literature; his extensive paper of 1923 was
expressly written to counteract the misleading account of Chinese knowledge popularised by Darwin and others. The essence of Moule's account is now more
accessible in volume 3 of Joseph Needham's treatise on Chinese scientific history.
 As early as the first century C.E., a reputed skeptical writer called Wang
Chhung saw fit to write an extensive article which ridiculed the popular superstition
about the murdered minister and advocated belief in the controlling influence
of the Moon. Needham translates the article in full. It was written about
the same time as the building of the first strong dykes to protect the adjacent land
from flooding by the bore."

Needham's Science And Civilisation In China, vol. 3 is available on Internet Archive, and his translation of Wang Chhung's article is on pp. 485-488. The writer is mostly concerned with debunking popular legends, but adds the following at the very end:

"Finally the rise of the wave follows the waxing and waning moon, smaller and larger, fuller or lesser, never the same. If Wu Tzu-Hsu makes the waves, his wrath must be governed by the phases of the moon!"


I believe Wang Chhung = Wang Chong (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_Chong)

@user103496 Yes, that is him, both are identified as the author of Lunheng. Differing transcriptions are common with Chinese names.
